# Angular universal is not rendering html on view page source

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I have installed angular universal and build is also made i have folders of browser and server inside the build but when i am serving the build it is not rendering the html inside view page source.
I have tried everything available online but i am not able to solve the issue basically it is cuba template.

```
import 'zone.js/node';

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/cuba/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';
  console.log("hello" ,indexHtml)

  // Configure Express to use Angular Universal's express-engine
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));
  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Serve static files from the /browser folder

  console.log('Before serving static files');

  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y',
  }));

  console.log('Before handling other routes');

  // Handle all other routes using the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;  // Use PORT without square brackets

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express serverr listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// The following code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

// Export the main.server module for Angular Universal
export * from './src/main.server';
```

Comment: how did you serve the build?

Comment: You need to add more data about the problem and what did you do for someone to help you.

Comment: I have use npm run serve:ssr and I have attached server.ts file if you need anythig else please tell @Sanxofon